# ag-grid: startEditing autoColumnDef for Tree View

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an `<ag-grid>` using Angular and one thing I'm trying to do is when you click a button to add a row to the grid, I want to be able to focus and start editing the input for that row and that column

In the documentation, I have been able to get this working with various columns in various `ag-grid`s in my app by using code like this:

```
this.gridApi.startEditingCell({
    rowIndex: 0,
    colKey: 'description'
});
```

However in one special case in one of my grids, I'm using the tree and `autoGroupColumnDef` like this:

```
<ag-grid-angular
        #agGrid
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
        id="myGrid"
        class="ag-theme-balham"
        [modules]="modules"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
        [rowData]="rowData"
        [treeData]="true"
        [getDataPath]="getDataPath"
        [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
        [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
        [groupDefaultExpanded]="groupDefaultExpanded"
        [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
        (cellValueChanged)="handleChanges($event)"
        (columnMoved)="handleColumnChanges($event)"
        [getRowNodeId]="getRowNodeId"
        [context]="this"
      ></ag-grid-angular>
```

And then in my typescript, I have my `autoGroupColumnDef` defined in my constructor like this:

```
this.autoGroupColumnDef = {
      editable: true,
      headerName: "Account #",
      field: "accountNum",
      filter: "agGroupCellRenderer",
      cellRendererParams: {
        suppressCount: true,
        innerRenderer: 'AccountNameColumnDisplayer',
      },
};
```

The problem is when I try to run the code like this:

```
this.gridApi.startEditingCell({
    rowIndex: 0,
    colKey: 'accountNum'
});
```

I get a warning that says `ag-grid-community.cjs.js:27041 ag-Grid: no column found for accountNum`

For the record, the data that I supply to `this.rowData` includes a property called `accountNum`

Is there something simple here that I'm not noticing or something I'm doing incorrectly? I have looked all over the ag-grid documentation and can't figure out how to solve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First off, lets be clear about the **colKey**. The colKey actually isn't directly tied to the field property. From the docs:

> Some of the API methods take Column Key (named colKey) which has type
>   Column | string. This means you can pass either a Column object (that
>   you receive from calling one of the other methods) or you pass in the
>   Column ID (which is a string). The Column ID is a property of the
>   column definition. If you do not provide the Column ID, the grid will
>   create one for you (first by trying to use the field if it is unique,
>   otherwise it will generate an ID).

So, the colKey is either the column object itself, or, the colId you set in the column definition, the field property, or a random string (in that order).

Your first instinct may be to go and set the colId property of your autoGroupColumnDef column. But alas! In my experience, agGrid throws another curve ball at you and this will not work either...why?

This is because agGrid always makes the autoGroupColumnDef colId: **ag-Grid-AutoColumn**

**TLDR**: use the colKey **"ag-Grid-AutoColumn"** for autoGroupColumnDef column!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can guess, I don't think your `accountNum` field is a part of `columnDefs`.

You need not provide field in `autoColumnGroupDef`, instead provide `accountNum` to actual columnDefs something like this -

```
  {
    field: 'accountNum',
    hide: true,
  }
```

Behind the scenes `autoGroupColumnDefs` is nothing but ag-grid group cell renderer on the column denoted with `rowGroup=true`.

Since your data is already in tree format, ag-grid takes care of grouping.

From the docs -

> When the grid is working with Tree Data there is no need to explicitly
>   specify a Column Group as the grid will use the Auto Column Group.
>
> The auto columns generated by the grid use the ag-Grid provided group
>   cell renderer. This means that gridOptions.autoGroupColumnDef can also
>   be used to pass additional properties to further customise how your
>   groups are displayed.

More details [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#auto-column-group)

Comment: Thanks for that answer, that actually does make a lot of sense. Apparently, because I'm using tree data, I get this warning now: `ag-Grid: rowGroup is not possible when doing tree data, your column definition should not have rowGroup` and it doesn't seem to allow me to edit the field still :/

Comment: if your data is in tree format already, you need not specify rowgroup. You can remove rowGroup property from the columndef

Comment: hey thanks for the response. I'm still having trouble with this, unfortunately. I've kept the `autoGroupColumnDef` since that seems to accomplish everything I need, except this. Perhaps I can do this a bit more manually? Like if there is a way to select a column in a row and then use `querySelectorAll` or something to that effect. Or is there a way to set the field on a `autoGroupColumnDef`?